# How to convert Chinese Html String into NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring, html-encode

For converting html string into NSString i am using below function

**Code Snippet :**

```
+(NSString *)getStringFromHtmlString:(NSString *)str
{

    NSData *stringData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSHTMLTextDocumentType
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

    NSAttributedString *decodedString;
    decodedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData
                                                     options:options
                                          documentAttributes:NULL
                                                       error:NULL];


    return decodedString.string;
}
```

Above method encode **English** text in proper format

But I want to encode **Chinese** text.

When Chinese string encode using above method it returns

I want proper encoding of chinese text.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the html string (chinese one).

Comment: <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 通是新型在线服务业</p>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding) options:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version:

```swift
let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
]
```